# how to add a formula to each cell in a column if another column has a value

Tags: excel, vba, formula, calculation

i have two dates. column G has start date and column H has end date. Column P has the amount of days between the two dates."Formula in Vba".
the formula i have works but i need it to only calculate only if there is an end date, if not use X1 "todays date.

```
Sub formulas()

   Range("P2:P100").Formula = "=H2:H100-G2:G100"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just modify your formula? Something like `Range("P2:P100").Fomula = "=H2-IF(ISBLANK(G2),$X$1,G2)"`. I think that's what you're getting at.

Comment: I have just tried that formula and it gives me a large negative number when it should be "3".  g = "5/5/2019" H = " " and X = "5/8/2019"

Comment: @Byron change `"=H2-IF(ISBLANK(G2),$X$1,G2)"` to `"=IF(G2<>"""",G2-IF(ISBLANK(H2),$X$1,H2),"""")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner isn't it H minus G, not G minus H?

Comment: @Byron I think I meant my original formula to be `=IF(ISBLANK(H2),$X$1,H2)-G2`, my mistake.

Comment: @BigBen yup, should be `"=IF(G2<>"""",IF(ISBLANK(H2),$X$1,H2)-G2,"""")"`

Comment: Scott, this one you sent worked perfectly. Thanks. Range("P2:P100").Formula = "=IF(G2<>"""",IF(ISBLANK(H2),$X$1,H2)-G2,"""")"